# Does the signaled state of a CONDITIONAL_VARIABLE persist even when there are no threads waiting for this signal?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

In Pthreads if a conditional variable is signaled and there are no threads blocking on a `pthread_cond_wait()` then this signal is lost.

When you use SetEvent() to signal an Event in Windows this event remains in the signaled state until another thread waits for this event object.

Which of the above behaviours do CONDITIONAL_VARIABLEs signaled using [WakeConditionVariable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687080(v=vs.85).aspx) follow?

Comment: It doesn't matter because the [intended usage pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx) is to verify the condition before waiting. If the condition variable is woken when there are no waiters, then the next waiter will verify the condition, see that it is met, and never call `SleepConditionVariable` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

That's an undocumented implementation detail, subject to change.  So your code *must* behave correctly in either case.  As Raymond already pointed out, if you [use condition variables as intended,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx) this happens automatically.

If for some reason you are not using the usual pattern, you should assume that the wake will be lost, but remember that threads waiting on a condition variable may be woken at any time for any reason or none:

> Condition variables are subject to spurious wakeups (those not associated with an explicit wake)

This means that if you assume the wake is lost, but in fact it isn't, it just looks like a spurious wakeup as far as the code is concerned.  Provided that the code deals with spurious wakeups correctly, it will also deal correctly with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From the following sentence on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687080(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Waking one thread is similar to setting an auto-reset event, while waking all 
>   threads is similar to pulsing a manual reset event but more reliable (see 
>   PulseEvent for details).

I deduce that the behavior is the same as in the pthread library. But as said in the comment above, this aspect actually does not matter much if you plan to use condition variables in a standard way.